# How to get previous state after click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $("div a").css("pointer-events", "all");
});

$("div").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("div a").css("pointer-events", "none");
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>
</div>
```

Generally, it works. But only once for every link. Instead of the `mouseleave`, I would need something like `after this click`. So after the click, the whole page should work like before, it shouldn't be just a one-way function.

I want to use it for something like [this](https://paal.org/2012/box2d/Box2dWithDOM.html). If you drag there links, they get fired automatically when you stop dragging. Links should only be fired after a click. I want to fix that.

How is it possible to do that? Would be soooo thankful for help! <3

Comment: If click div once, should add css 'pointer-events:all' and click again, should be "pointer-events", "none"? you want like this?

Comment: You can set a global variable that other event listeners check.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're really trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: "pointer-events: all;" should work only for the moment when the link gets clicked. But if there is a drag or something like that, there should be a "pointer-events: none;". I edited my question.

Comment: @Barmar – How can I write a global variable for that?

Comment: Seems like you should be using `dragstart` and `dragend`, not `click`.

Comment: You can also use `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

Comment: @Barmar – It always works only once for each link. I would need to have to previous state after a click.

Comment: You can use the `.one()` method to add an event listener that removes itself after it's triggered.

Comment: @Barmar – I just tried it, but I failed. Could you show me how you would code that please?

Comment: `$("div").one("click", function() {
  $("div a").css("pointer-events", "all");
});`

Comment: I'm still not really sure I understand what you want to do, so that may not be right.

Comment: @Barmer – Thanks. With this code, it works only for one link once. Could you look at this page please? https://paal.org/2012/box2d/Box2dWithDOM.html – If you drag there for example the box with the Twitter link, and stop dragging when your cursor is above the link, then the link gets fired. But the link only should be fired after a "click", and not just after "dragend".

Answer (score 0):

Since a click Event does not actually fire until you press then release, maybe you want to do something along the lines of:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// tiny library above - magic below can be put on separate page using a load event *(except // end load line)*
const box = I('box'), bS = box.style, goto = I('goto');
let posX, posY;
function touchFun(e){
  const b = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  e.preventDefault(); posX = e.clientX-b.left; posY = e.clientY-b.top;
}
function moveFun(e){
  if(posX !== undefined){
    bS.left = e.clientX-posX+'px'; bS.top = e.clientY-posY+'px';
  }
}
function stopFun(){
  posX = posY = undefined;
}
if(mobile){
  box.ontouchstart = goto.ontouchstart = touchFun; ontouchmove = moveFun;
  ontouchend = stopFun;
}
else{
  box.onmousedown = goto.onmousedown = touchFun; onmousemove = moveFun;
  onmouseup = stopFun;
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{ /* set font individually - may create white space on line breaks */
  box-sizing:border-box; font:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.full{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#main{
  position:relative;
}
#box{
  position:absolute; display:inline-block; background:#ff0; padding:15px; left:100px; top:50px;
}
a{
  font-size:22px; white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='full' id='main'>
    <div id='box'><a id='goto' href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```